# How to write a query for unserialized categories

Tags: php, mysql

so my function post() does the next thing:

```
$category = serialize($postdata['post_category']);
        $query = "
                 INSERT INTO posts(post_title, post_content, post_category)
                 VALUES ('$postdata[post_title]', '$postdata[post_content]', '$category')
                 ";
```

inserts serialized data into the database, but i have a problem when calling a function to show only those posts which have same category, a function for that looks like this:

```
public function cat($cat){
        global $db;
        $query = "
                 SELECT * FROM posts
                 WHERE post_category LIKE '%$cat%'
                 ";
        return $db->select($query);
    }
```

So my question is: is it better to insert unserialized data into database for this particular case (and how to do that) or is it better to pull serialized data and then unserialize it for showing some particular posts (same as previous, tried a couple of options and had no luck achieving the right result) ?

Comment: This is where you use another table or two and use `JOIN`s. Read up on [database normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Additionally, **you are wide open to SQL injection attacks**

Comment: @Bojangles do you mean that i need a separate table for categories ?

Comment: Yes, and most likely a pivot table if you have a many to many relationship

Comment: @Bojangles would appreciate if you would be so kind to paste a link for me so i can read more on those security issues

Comment: @user3670146 Just google "sql injection", "deprecated mysql api", "prepared statements php mysql", "pdo", etc.

Comment: What does post_category hold? Is it a php array containing just a list of the categories that a post is associated with? Are those category names, or an id of the category? Normally you would have a table of categories, a table of posts, and another table containing one row per post per associated category (and these rows would just need to contain the id of the post and the id of the category). While is it technically possible to break down a php serialised array in an SQL statement, it is something only really worth doing for amusement, and not something to use in a real system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$postdata['post_category']` is an array, you could also insert multiple categories in the same column:

```
$category = ',' . implode(',', $postdata['post_category']) . ',';
$query = "
     INSERT INTO posts(post_title, post_content, post_category)
     VALUES ('$postdata[post_title]', '$postdata[post_content]', '$category')
     ";
```

Mind that you always should have `comma` at the end and the beggining of the categories string like so: `,1,2,3,4,`!

To select the posts from a category:

```
public function cat($cat){
    global $db;
    $query = "
             SELECT * FROM posts
             WHERE post_category LIKE ',$cat,'
             ";
    return $db->select($query);
}
```

But this method will not allow you to select posts from multiple categories.

**Note:** You should consider learning to use multiple tables and `JOIN`-ining them. One table for posts, one table for categories and one table post_to_categories, where all the categories with their specific posts are linked.

Comment: If storing a comma separated list (generally a bad idea) then FIND_IN_SET would be better than using LIKE, an also removes the need for leading and trailing commas.

Comment: I agree, but he wanted a fast solution without learning new stuff. I used to be like that, because I didn't know where to search for new ideas. Now I use linked tables, like I wrote in the answer.

Comment: @machineaddict what should table post_to_categories contain ? an ID for post and an ID for category ?

Comment: @machineaddict are there any examples you know to help me out at the beginning ?

Comment: @user3670146: something like [this](http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/254/products-multiple-categories-mysql-database/), even though its not complete, its just the start on how this works...

Answer (score 1):

```
If you want to store the categories array, you can use implode(',', $postdata['post_category'])

$category = implode(',', $postdata['post_category']);
$query = "
            INSERT INTO posts(post_title, post_content, post_category)
            VALUES ('$postdata[post_title]', '$postdata[post_content]', '$category')
"; 

and if you want to search the post based on some category you can use

public function cat($cat){
        global $db;
        $query = "
                 SELECT * FROM posts
                 WHERE find_in_set(".$cat.",post_category)
                 ";
        return $db->select($query);
}
```